# How to use the same selector repeatedly in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use my selector "olmaps" several times in the same component, but it doesn't work correctly. 
In the app every map should be loaded in his own window. 
But the map gets only rendered in the first window. The second map, that should be loaded in the second window, gets just rendered in the first window too.
Exactly the same with every added map. 

**app.component.html**

```
 <jqxWindow>
      <div id="windowHeader">
                    <span>
                        Different Maps
                    </span>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow: hidden;" id="windowContent">
        <jqxTabs>
          <ul style="margin-left: 30px;">
            <li>Map 1</li>
            <li>Map 2</li>
            <li>Map 3</li>
            <li>Map 4</li>
            <li>Map 5</li>
          </ul>

          <div>
            <olmap></olmap>
          </div>

          <div>
            <olmap></olmap>

          </div>


          <div>

            <olmap></olmap>
          </div>

          <div>

            <olmap></olmap>

          <div>

            <olmap></olmap>
          </div>
        </jqxTabs>
      </div>
    </jqxWindow>
```

**map.component.html**

```
 <div  id="map"></div>
```

**map.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, QueryList} from '@angular/core';

import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  host: {'[id]': 'mapId'},
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})



export class MapComponent implements OnInit {



 // id: string = ""  ;
  mapId: string;



  constructor() {
    this.mapId = "map";
  }

  map: ol.Map = undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({

      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([50.7753, 6.0839]),
        zoom: 3
      })
    });
  }

}
```

Perhaps this could be solved with a dynamic id, the map could get every time the selector would be used?
But i don't find any solution in the angular 2/4 jungle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngFor for the repeated task:

```
 <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]">
       Map {{i}}
       <olmap [mapId]="i"></olmap>
     </li>
<ul>
```

In the component:

```
  @Input() mapId: number;
```

and filter map to get mapId element for each olmap

Comment: Thank you! But *ngFor is completly destroying my HTML. How can i set the reference for my id in map.component.html?

Comment: you should set it in <olmap>'s component